# How do I checkout with Git a branch on a Fork of my Origin?

Tags: git, github, branch, git-checkout

There is a repository `/abc` on GitHub that I forked. So my fork is at `me/abc`.

Jim also forked `/abc`, with their repo at `Jim/abc`. Jim added a branch called `2.0`. This branch doesn't exist on `/abc`.

I have already cloned by fork from `me/abc` locally (used GitHub for Window). I would now like to make some modifications to the `2.0` branch from `Jim/abc` locally, and them commit and push the changes back.

What is the best way to go about doing this?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I was able to accomplish this by doing the following:

**1. Add Remote pointing to `Jim/abc`:**

```
git remote add jim https://github.com/jim/abc.git
```

**2. Fetch the repository `Jim`:**

```
git fetch jim
```

**3. Checkout the branch from the `Jim/abc` remote:**

```
git checkout jim/2.0
```

Branch is now in "detached HEAD" state.

**4. Create local branch:**

```
git checkout -b 2.0
```

Branch is now checked out and ready for work locally.

Comment: Worked for me . Thanks

Comment: thank you, super clear :)